# Netbeans how to set command line arguments in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, arguments

I am trying to set command line arguments in a Netbeans 7.1 Java project on Windows 7 64 bit.

Netbeans is not passing the arguments I give it.

I go to `Project` --> `Properties` --> `Run` --> and type the arguments next to "Arguments" however the arguments are not passed to the program.  How do I pass them?

Comment: Please show your main class.  Are you using a NetBeans-created build.xml or your own build.xml?

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the run configuration that is used when you run the project? Make sure you select the correct configuration in the drop down of the toolbar

Comment: If you want it to work for a single file.. call the main in some other class `MainProgram.main(new String[]{"arg0","arg1"});`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I am guessing that you are running the file using `Run | Run File` (or shift-F6) rather than `Run | Run Main Project`.  The NetBeans 7.1 help file (F1 is your friend!) states for the Arguments parameter:

> Add arguments to pass to the main class during application execution.
>   Note that arguments cannot be passed to individual files.

I verified this with a little snippet of code:

```
public class Junk
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (String s : args)
            System.out.println("arg -> " + s);
    }
}
```

I set Run -> Arguments to `x y z`.  When I ran the file by itself I got no output.  When I ran the project the output was:

```
arg -> x
arg -> y
arg -> z
```

Comment: We can pass command line argument even to a single Java file now using a community contributed plugin for NetBeans IDE 8.0 https://github.com/tusharvjoshi/nbrunwithargs

Comment: Oh, yes, this plugin was created for Ant based Java projects only.  I will modify it to not show the NPE in Maven projects.  This plugin needs additional functionality of Maven projects, the plugin is open for pull requests and any help provided by community for this feature

Comment: If I get a chance I will take a look to see what's involved for making it work with Gradle projects as well, though Gradle itself requires a plugin so not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 24):

1. Create the Java code that can receive an argument as a command line argument.

   ```java
   class TestCode{
       public static void main(String args[]){
           System.out.println("first argument is: "+args[0]);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Run the program without arguments (press <kbd>F6</kbd>).
3. In the Output window, at the bottom, click the double yellow arrow (or the yellow button) to open a **Run** dialog.
4. If the argument you need to pass is `testArgument`, then here in this window pass the argument as `application.args=testArgument`.

This will give the output as follows in the same Output window:

```
first argument is: testArgument
```

For Maven, the instructions are similar, but change the `exec.args` property instead:

```
exec.args=-classpath %classpath package.ClassName PARAM1 PARAM2 PARAM3
```

Note: Use single quotes for string parameters that contain spaces.

Comment: If I insert *application.args=testArgument* after clicking the yellow button, then, once I click Run on that window, I get the following error:   *Target "application.args=9" does not exist in the project "{0} (run)"*     - I entered a 9 now, but what I enter as an argument isn't relevant for the error...

Comment: just to know, on my NetBeans 11.3, if the "compile on save" option is disabled, the "application.args" property does not work

Answer (score 14):

If it's a Maven project then Netbeans is running your application using the *exec-maven-plugin* so you'll need to append your options onto the existing `exec.args` property found in the *Run Maven* dialog. This dialog can be accessed from the the *Output* window by pressing the yellow double arrow icon.

[image]

Comment: This is the easiest method that I've found for NetBeans Maven projects!  The section "Remember as" and other options does not appear for me when that dialog opens.  I have to resize the dialog before they become visible.  Even after I have used "Remember as 'foo'", I don't know how to re-run that configuration.  I don't know where it was "remembered".

Answer (score 10):

For a Maven project using NetBeans 8.x:

1. Click **Run >> Set Project Configuration >> Customise**
2. Select **Actions**
3. Select **Run file via main()**
4. Set name/value pair to include the arguments.
5. Click **OK**

An example name/value pair might resemble:

```
javax.persistence.jdbc.password=PASSWORD
```

Then run your project:

1. Open and focus the Java class that includes `main(...)`.
2. Press <kbd>F6</kbd> to run the program.

The command line parameters should appear in the Run window.

Note that to obtain the value form with the program, use [`System.getProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)).

Additional actions for **Test file**, **Run project**, and other ways to run the application can have arguments defined. Repeat the steps above for the different actions to accomplish this task.

Comment: What if Set Project Configuration is greyed out?? Grails project.

Comment: Environment variables obtained from `System.getProperty()` are not the same thing as "command-line arguments".  If you need to provide the arguments as seen by the array `args` in `main(String[] args)` then it is necessary to edit the Maven variable `exec.args`  The answer by "Leif Gruenwoldt" shows one way to do that.

Answer (score 8):

```
import java.io.*;
class Main
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    int n1,n2,n3,l;
    n1=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    n2=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    n3=Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    
    if(n1>n2)
    {
        l=n1;
    }
    else
    {
        l=n2;
    }
    
    if(l<n3)
    {
        System.out.println("largest no is "+n3);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("largest no is "+l);
    }
    
}}
```

Consider above program, in this program I want to pass 3 no's from Command Line, to do so.

Step 1 : Right Click on Cup and Saucer icon, u'll see this window

[image: 1]

Step 2: Click on Properties

Step 3: Click Run _> Arguments _> type three no's eg.
32  98  16
then click OK. Plz add space between two arguments. See here

[image: 2]

Step 4: Run the Program by using F6.

Answer (score 2):

In NetBeans IDE 8.0 you can use a community contributed plugin https://github.com/tusharvjoshi/nbrunwithargs which will allow you to pass arguments while Run Project or Run Single File command.

For passing arguments to Run Project command either you have to set the arguments in the Project properties Run panel, or use the new command available after installing the plugin which says Run with Arguments

For passing command line arguments to a Java file having main method, just right click on the method and choose Run with Arguments command, of this plugin

UPDATE (24 mar 2014) This plugin is now available in NetBeans Plugin Portal that means it can be installed from Plugins dialog box from the available plugins shown from community contributed plugins, in NetBeans IDE 8.0

[image: Run with Arguments plugin as shown in Plugin dialog box]

Comment: Does not work for me.. It says cannot found main class

Comment: Doesn't work for Maven projects - see this [bug report](https://github.com/tusharvjoshi/nbrunwithargs/issues/3)

Comment: Oh, yes, this plugin was created for Ant based Java projects only. I will modify it to not show the NPE in Maven projects. This plugin needs additional functionality of Maven projects, the plugin is open for pull requests and any help provided by community for this feature

Answer (score 1):

For passing arguments to Run Project command either you have to set the arguments in the Project properties Run panel

Answer (score 1):

Note that from Netbeans 8 there is no Run panel in the project Properties.

To do what you want I simply add the following line (example setting the locale) in my project's properties file:

```
run.args.extra=--locale fr:FR
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using MyEclipse and want to add args before run the program, Then do as follows:
1.0) Run -> Run Config
2.1) Click "Arguments" on the right panel
2.2)add your args in the "Program Args" box, separated by blank

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, use the VM args in NetBeans:

```
@Value("${a.b.c:#{abc}}"
...

@Value("${e.f.g:#{efg}}"
...
```

Netbeans:

```
-Da.b.c="..." -De.f.g="..."
```

Properties -> Run -> VM Options -> -De.f.g=efg -Da.b.c=abc

From the commandline

```
java -jar <yourjar> --Da.b.c="abc"
```