# Massive Online Analysis in Netbeans: Can not access instrumentation environment

Tags: java, netbeans, machine-learning

I'm trying to run some demo code of Massive Online Analysis (MOA) in Netbeans. Here is the code:

```
package javaapplication10_moa;

import moa.classifiers.trees.HoeffdingTree;
import moa.classifiers.Classifier;
import moa.core.TimingUtils;
import moa.streams.generators.RandomRBFGenerator;
import com.yahoo.labs.samoa.instances.Instance;
import java.io.IOException;


/**
 *
 * @author LENOVO
 */
public class JavaApplication10_MOA {

        public JavaApplication10_MOA(){            
        }

        public void run(int numInstances, boolean isTesting){
                Classifier learner = new HoeffdingTree();
                RandomRBFGenerator stream = new RandomRBFGenerator();
                stream.prepareForUse();

                learner.setModelContext(stream.getHeader());
                learner.prepareForUse();

                int numberSamplesCorrect = 0;
                int numberSamples = 0;
                boolean preciseCPUTiming = TimingUtils.enablePreciseTiming();
                long evaluateStartTime = TimingUtils.getNanoCPUTimeOfCurrentThread();
                while (stream.hasMoreInstances() && numberSamples < numInstances) {
                        Instance trainInst = stream.nextInstance().getData();
                        if (isTesting) {
                                if (learner.correctlyClassifies(trainInst)){
                                        numberSamplesCorrect++;
                                }
                        }
                        numberSamples++;
                        learner.trainOnInstance(trainInst);
                }
                double accuracy = 100.0 * (double) numberSamplesCorrect/ (double) numberSamples;
                double time = TimingUtils.nanoTimeToSeconds(TimingUtils.getNanoCPUTimeOfCurrentThread()- evaluateStartTime);
                System.out.println(numberSamples + " instances processed with " + accuracy + "% accuracy in "+time+" seconds.");
        }        

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                JavaApplication10_MOA exp = new JavaApplication10_MOA();
                exp.run(1000000, true);
        } 

}
```

And here is the output:

> Can not access instrumentation environment. Please check if jar file
>   containing SizeOfAgent class is  specified in the java's "-javaagent"
>   command line argument. 1000000 instances processed with 91.0458%
>   accuracy in 5.5 seconds. BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)

The thing is Netbeans was unable to access instrumentation environment, which I understand to be something similar to a profile. I have tried the suggestions from [Netbeans how to set command line arguments in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168759/netbeans-how-to-set-command-line-arguments-in-java), by going to Run -> Set Project Configuration -> Customize. Set Arguments to  -javaagent:sizeofag.jar . Yet it does not work! :( 
Please help me, thank you very much

Comment: Did you use standard java project in netbeans or probably based on maven?

Comment: @VladislavKysliy Just standard netbeans :(

Answer (score 0):

I usually setup java agent via `Project->Properties->Run->VM` and options like this:

```
-javaagent:"<full path to jar>/target.jar"
```

Moreover I found old topic on netbens forum [Configuring javaagent in NetBeans](https://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic24942.html) so it should work.

PS: please have a look below [image: example]

BTW I downloaded moa-release-2016.04.zip, unpacked, created simple java project in Netbeans, added path to `<path>/moa-release-2016.04/lib/moa-2016.04.jar` in Library section and ran your code without any errors or warnings. I didn't even mention javaagent in `Run` section. Here is my output window:

```
run:
1000000 instances processed with 91.0458% accuracy in 5.480392592 seconds.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Comment: Tried this -javaagent:D:\Hoctap\Massive_Online_Analysis\lib\sizeofag-1.0.0.jar but it did not work :( Also i downloaded the same file as you did but it's not working either :(

Comment: @DangManhTruong I think for windows you should use -javaagent:"D:/Hoctap/Massive_Online_Analysis/lib/sizeofag-1.‌​0.0.jar"

Comment: @DangManhTruong Checked on Windows - everything fine. It seems you have some issues on local environment, please check your java version

Comment: @DangManhTruong I packed my netbeans project please check it out http://dropcanvas.com/wvs90

Comment: Sorry can you upload it again the link has expired :(

Comment: @DangManhTruong  ok. here https://www.dropbox.com/s/0o8ffayib7o88oy/JavaApplication10_MOA%281%29.zip?dl=0